# Migrating (backing up) SFDX authenticated logins to a new machine

Tags: salesforcedx, authentication

Is it possible to migrate/backup locally authenticated orgs to a new machine without having to re-authenticate on another machine?

After running `sfdx force:auth:web:login`, the authentication flow here saves a token to the machine (works its magic under the hood). Can we copy and paste wherever this is saved onto a new machine without having to re-authenticate with the Salesforce Orgs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by copying the `.sf` and `.sfdx` folder contents in the user's home directory (which varies by OS). For Windows you will typically find these in `C:\Users\username\`.

Be very careful with these details since the JSON files (one per org connection) in these folders include both the access and refresh tokens and therefore can allow someone to gain access to the org without need to login.

As per comments, with the introduction of the SF CLI you also need to copy a password from your keychain.

Comment: This seems to no longer works today, I get this error "authdecrypterror"

Comment: There is now a `.sf` folder if you are using up-to-date CLI.